# Coldfusion Get all IP addresses from a given IP4 address range

Tags: java, coldfusion, network-programming, cfml, cfc

Building monitoring tool where administrator will input ip range 
for example.

Start : 192.168.1.3 End: 192.168.1.30

Output: structure or array

- 192.168.1.4
- 192.168.1.5
- 192.168.1.6...so on

  OR

Start:192.168.1.50  End:192.169.1.12

Output: structure or array

- 192.168.1.50
- 192.168.1.51...
- 192.169.1.3

How can i achieve this result.Is there any java library available ?

Comment: Ben Nadel solved about half of your problem here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1830-converting-ip-addresses-to-and-from-integer-values-with-coldfusion.htm

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057853/how-to-convert-string-ip-numbers-to-integer-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that IP4 addresses are 32bit (each of the 4 elements are 8 bit) you could do the following:

- convert both IP addresses to 32 bit integer
- create a loop that iterates from `begin_int` to `end_int`
- convert the loop index back to IP4 address

(sorry for not giving code, but my java knowledge is limited)

**Update** (google is your friend) (well, you could do it also yourself!)
I took my inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241229/going-from-127-0-0-1-to-2130706433-and-back-again). As I said: No guarantee that this works!

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

// Convert from an IPv4 address to an integer
InetAddress from_inet = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.50");
int from_address = ByteBuffer.wrap(from_inet.getAddress()).getInt();


// Convert from an IPv4 address to an integer
InetAddress to_inet = InetAddress.getByName("192.169.1.12");
int to_address = ByteBuffer.wrap(to_inet.getAddress()).getInt();


for(int i = from_address; i < to_address; i++) {
    // Convert from integer to an IPv4 address
    InetAddress foo = InetAddress.getByName(i);
    String address = foo.getHostAddress();
    System.out.println(address);
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response could give me any example of code? it will be great help i don't know much about IPs. why i need ips because im pulling XML file from ips.