# Convert IP (string) into long in elasticsearch/kibana scripted fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a field in a doc that is a string representation of ipv4 ("1.2.3.4"), the name of the field is "originating_ip".
I'm trying to use the scripted fields using the painless language in order to add a new field (originating_ip_calc) to have the int (long) representation of said IPv4.

The following script works in groovy (and from what I understand this should basically work almost the same), but it seems like almost is not in this specific case.

```
​String[] ipAddressInArray = "1.2.3.4".split("\\.");

long result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressInArray.length; i++) {
    int power = 3 - i;
    int ip = Integer.parseInt(ipAddressInArray[i]);
    long longIP = (ip * Math.pow(256, power)).toLong();
    result = result + longIP;
}
return result;
```

I also looking in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836155/convert-ip-between-ipv4-and-numerical-format-in-java) and as you can see from the code above it is based on one of the answers there.

Also tried to work with InetAddress but no luck.

Comment: You seem to be aware of IPv6; a pitty you did not ask for more. `long longIP = ip << power*8L; result |= longIP;` (bit shift left, long result for 8L, bitwise or).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Elasticsearch painless scripting you can use code like the following:

```
POST ip_search/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "originating_ip_calc": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
String ip_addr = params['_source']['originating_ip'];
def ip_chars = ip_addr.toCharArray();
int chars_len = ip_chars.length;
long result = 0;
int cur_power = 0;
int last_dot = chars_len;
for(int i = chars_len -1; i>=-1; i--) {
  if (i == -1 || ip_chars[i] == (char) '.' ){
    result += (Integer.parseInt(ip_addr.substring(i+ 1, last_dot)) * Math.pow(256, cur_power));
    last_dot = i;
    cur_power += 1;
  }
}         
return result
""",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": ["originating_ip"]
}
```

(Note that I used [Kibana console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.4/console-kibana.html) to send the request to ES, it does some escaping to make this a valid JSON before sending.)

This will give a response like this:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "ip_search",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "originating_ip": "10.0.0.1"
    },
    "fields": {
      "originating_ip_calc": [
        167772161
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "ip_search",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "originating_ip": "1.2.3.4"
    },
    "fields": {
      "originating_ip_calc": [
        16909060
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But why does it have to be this way?

### Why does the approach with `.split` not work?

If you send the code from the question to ES it replies with an error like this:

```
      "script": "String[] ipAddressInArray = \"1.2.3.4\".split(\"\\\\.\");\n\nlong result = 0;\nfor (int i = 0; i < ipAddressInArray.length; i++) {\n    int power = 3 - i;\n    int ip = Integer.parseInt(ipAddressInArray[i]);\n    long longIP = (ip * Math.pow(256, power)).toLong();\n    result = result + longIP;\n}\nreturn result;",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown call [split] with [1] arguments on type [String]."
```

This is mainly due to the fact that Java's [`String.split()` is not considered safe to use](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26338#issuecomment-324310877) (because it creates regex Pattern implicitly). They suggest to use [Pattern#split](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/painless-api-reference.html#painless-api-reference-Pattern) but to do so you should have regexes enabled in your index.

By default, they are disabled:

```
      "script": "String[] ipAddressInArray = /\\./.split(\"1.2.3.4\");...
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "Regexes are disabled. Set [script.painless.regex.enabled] to [true] in elasticsearch.yaml to allow them. Be careful though, regexes break out of Painless's protection against deep recursion and long loops."
```

### Why do we have to do an explicit cast `(char) '.'`?

So, we have to split the string on dots manually. The straightforward approach is to compare each char of the string with `'.'` (which in Java means `char` literal, not `String`).

But for `painless` it means `String`. So we have to make an explicit cast to `char` (because we are iterating over an array of chars).

### Why do we have to work with char array directly?

Because apparently `painless` does not allow `.length` method of `String` as well:

```
    "reason": {
      "type": "script_exception",
      "reason": "compile error",
      "script_stack": [
        "\"1.2.3.4\".length",
        "         ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script": "\"1.2.3.4\".length",
      "lang": "painless",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown field [length] for type [String]."
      }
    }
```

### So why is it called `painless` ?

Although I can't find any historical note on the naming after quick googling, from the [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-scripting-painless.html) and some experience (like above in this answer) I can infer that it is designed to be painless *to use in production*.

It's predecessor, [Groovy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-scripting-groovy.html), was a ticking bomb due to resources usage and [security vulnerabilities](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-scripting-security.html). So Elasticsearch team created a very limited subset of Java/Groovy scripting which would have predictable performance and would not contain those security vulnerabilities, and called it `painless`.

If there is anything true about `painless` scripting language, is that it is **limited** and **sandboxed**.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks for that. For some reasons something still doesn't work. I'll try to understand what/why and approve the answer after that :) Thanks again!

Comment: Needed to use `doc['originating_ip.keyword'].value` in order to get the string value of the originating_ip field. Thanks!