# sort a list of ips in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of ip objects that have their v4 address as a String. (ip is in decimal)

Now I want to sort this list in ascending order with the ip parts as search keys.

This was my first approach. It works but it needs four functions to return each part of the ip.

```
Comparator<IP> ipComparator =
  Comparator
  .comparing(IP::getFirstPart)
  .thenComparing(IP::getSecondPart)
  .thenComparing(IP::getThirdPart)
  .thenComparing(IP::getFourthPart);
```

I would like to do something like this

```
Comparator<IP> ipComparator =
  Comparator
  .comparing(IP::getPart(0))
  .thenComparing(IP::getPart(1))
  .thenComparing(IP::getPart(2))
  .thenComparing(IP::getPart(3));
```

What is the easiest way to implement this without defining a function to return each part of the ip?

Comment: An IP address is just a representation of a 32 bit integer. You can [convert them to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057853/how-to-convert-string-ip-numbers-to-integer-in-java) for sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

- create a list to hold the ip addresses.

```
List<InetAddress> ips = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then create some to sort. I am demonstrating the [Inet4Address](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Inet4Address.html) class to accept either a dotted quad or a byte array.  Then shuffle the list.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 23; i+= 2) {
    ips.add(Inet4Address.getByName("192.168.1."+i));
    ips.add(Inet4Address.getByAddress(new byte[]{(byte)192, (byte)168, 
                                                 (byte)1, (byte)(i+1)}));
}
Collections.shuffle(ips);
```

According to the source code the `hashCode` for `Inet4Address` is the address itself. And that could be used for sorting without using a key extractor.  But as far as I can tell it is not documented and therefore should not be relied upon. So it can be done as follows:

- use a `ByteBuffer` to wrap the byte array returned from `getAddress()` and retrieve the `int` value.
- then. since the high order bit can arbitrarily appear in IP addresses, do an unsigned compare on the two ip's as applied by the sort

```
ips.sort(Comparator.comparing(ip->
            ByteBuffer.wrap(ip.getAddress()).getInt(),
            (i1, i2) -> Integer.compareUnsigned(i1, i2)));
```

Now print the results.

```
ips.forEach(ip->System.out.println(ip.getHostAddress()));
```

prints

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
192.168.1.15
192.168.1.16
192.168.1.17
192.168.1.18
192.168.1.19
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.21
192.168.1.22
```

Answer (score 0):

If you represent them as a natural string like "192.168.2.4", then they won't be sortable, but if you zero-prefix each octet like, "192.168.002.004" then the strings will sort as expected.  Similarly, you can represent them in hexadecimal like, "C0A80204".  The key is fixed width per octet.

Alternatively, you can represent the 4 octets as a single number.  The thing to be careful of is that if the first octet is 127 or higher, then a 32-bit integer will treat it as a negative number, which will affect the sort order.  The easiest solution (if not the most memory-efficient) is to return it as a long value.

Comment: Surprised to learn that Java has no unsigned types

Comment: @meagar It would be helpful.  But in this case one can use `Integer.compareUnsigned(a,b);` as I explained in my answer.